# Solving family of complicated limits in a smarter way

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

In my book there is a sequence of limits exercises of the family $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{1}{f(x)} - \frac{1}{g(x)}\right)$$ I tend to put a common denominator so it becomes $\frac{g(x)-f(x)}{f(x)g(x)}$ and then apply L'Hopital rule.

However they often become too verbose and complicated. I believe there must be a clever way of doing this. For example, the limit:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{1}{\tan^2(x)} - \frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$
or
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)} - \frac{1}{x^2}\right).$$

They easily become too complicated, and since there are a lot of exercises in this form I think it means it could be done in a simple way.

Comment: Well, $\lim_{x\to \infty}x^{-2}=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} \csc^2(x)$ doesn't exist, so...

Comment: Have you studied Taylor's expansion yet?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter No, I do not. It's $x \rightarrow 0$. I will edit